# Configure LXC to use wireless hosted network

Tags: networking, docker, virtual-machine, lxc, bridge

I found most of the configuration is for giving static or private network. But I want it to act as a different machine so it will get a separate IP address from the DHCP and I want to do it through nmcli.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using docker as tagged, rather than LXC, use [`pipework`](https://github.com/jpetazzo/pipework#connect-a-container-to-a-local-physical-interface) to map the wlan interface from the host to the container

```
pipework eth2 $CONTAINERID 10.10.9.9/24
```

or alternatively let the container do the dhcp negotiation for you

```
pipework eth1 $CONTAINERID dhclient
```

This setup is based on a macvlan interface so the same concept should work with LXC you just won't get the [easy front end](https://www.flockport.com/lxc-macvlan-networking/).

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused if this is a docker question or an LXC question.

**EDIT: as per the comments, wlan interface support in a bridge depends on the wlan vendor. It may work, or it may not work at all.**

In any case, you should be able to create a bridge, add your wlan0 interface to the bridge, and then have your LXC container connect to this bridge directly. Then, when you run your DHCP client in the container, it will grab it from the wlan0 interface.

**Configure bridge (manually for now)**

```
# ifconfig wlan0 up
# brctl addbr br0
# brctl addif br0 wlan0
# ifconfig br0 up
# dhclient br0
```

**Configure LXC configuration**

If using traditional priviliged LXC, edit the container's config file at `/var/lib/lxc/$NAME/config`,
 and update this value to point to your new bridge.

`lxc.network.link = br0`

**Run DHCP in container**

```
# lxc-attach -n $NAME
# dhclient eth0
# ip a
```

If the output to `ip a` shows the desired IP, you're all set!

**If you want to make the configuration persistent, you'll have to add the bridge to your `/etc/network/interfaces` file.**

Comment: WI-FI network interfaces can have many restrictions (or more restrictions than wired interfaces) and sometimes cant work as bridge. It depends on vendor.

Answer (score 0):

[IEEE 802.11 doesn’t like multiple MAC addresses](https://blog.flameeyes.eu/2011/12/the-problem-with-wireless-bridging) on a single client, so bridge and [macvlans are not the right solution here](http://hicu.be/macvlan-vs-ipvlan).

Use ipvlan in L2 mode.

Comment: You seem to be missing a url in your answer.